# Can opencv be used with apple’s coremL (Neural Engine)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, metal, apple-m1

I have a simple opencv script in python running on an M1 Mac to detect objects with. Is it possible to use Apple’s coreML to accelerate OpenCV? I've installed TensorFlow-metal (using https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)and I'm using TensorFlow through OpenCV. Will OpenCV use this metal version of TensorFlow or is it just building the net defined in TensorFlow and using its own framework? Is there a way to get OpenCV to use the neural engine on an M1 Mac or to verify whether it is using it or not?

Comment: "I'm using TensorFlow through OpenCV" -- opencv is not using any tf or coreml components at all.

Comment: In addition the comment above, there is no way to ensure a workload will run on the Neural Engine or verify that it does. The Neural Engine is largely a  Black Box.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is not the information one would hope for but keeps me from running down a rabbit hole